# Trying to get my delete statement to work

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-delete

I want to remove rows from a table, based on a column from another table as such:

```
Table1:            Table2:
value              value, i
```

If table2.i is less than 1, delete corresponding row from table1 (but keep it in table2).

The problem is that value isn't unique, so if I have this for exampe:

```
 Table1            table2
+-------+        +-----------+
| value |        | value | i |
+-------+        +-----------+
|   5   |        |  5    | 0 |
|   3   |        |  5    | 3 |
+-------+        |  3    | 0 |
                 |  3    | 0 |
                 +-----------+
```

Value 3 should be deleted from table1 (since all occurrences in table2 has i<1) but value 5 should stay(because of i=3 row in table2)

My code so far (doesn't work):

```
DELETE FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE (SELECT MIN(Table2.i) FROM Table1, Table2
       WHERE Table1.value = Table2.value) < 1;
```

Problem is: since my subquery returns min for ALL rows, everything gets deleted.

And I can't use "group by" in my subquery because then my comparison isn't allowed.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I Use SQL version: 11.0.2100.60 (Microsoft SQL Server management studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1  
                   FROM Table2          
                  WHERE Table2.i > 0 
                    AND Table2.value = Table1.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you are using min, instead u should use max:

try this

```
     DELETE FROM Table1
   WHERE Table1.value1 = Table2.value1
   and (SELECT MAX(Table2.i) FROM Table2
   WHERE Table1.value1 = Table2.value1) < 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'd start by writing a query that selects the rows you want to delete,

```
SELECT
            *
    FROM
       Table1
    EXCEPT
    (
    SELECT
                t1.value
        FROM
                Table1 t1
            JOIN
                Table2 t2
                    ON t2.value = t1.value
        WHERE
                t2.i > 0
    );
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91092d/1)

Then change the SELECT to a DELETE

```
DELETE Table1
    FROM
       Table1 t1
    WHERE
       t1.value NOT IN
    (
    SELECT
                t1.value
        FROM
                Table1 t1
            JOIN
                Table2 t2
                    ON t2.value = t1.value
        WHERE
                t2.i > 0
    );
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91092d/4)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
delete from table1 where value in
    (select value from table2 group by value having max(i) < 1)
```

Grouping table 2 by value and using `having` to detect where the maximum is less than 1 allows you to select the correct values for deletion from table 1.

`having` is basically a `where` clause which comes into play *after* aggregation so can be used with `max` and so on.

Here's a script to show it in action:

```
DROP TABLE TABLE1;
DROP TABLE TABLE2;
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (VALUE INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (VALUE INTEGER, I INTEGER);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (5, 0);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (5, 3);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (3, 0);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (3, 0);

SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
SELECT * FROM TABLE2;

DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE VALUE IN
  (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY VALUE HAVING MAX(I) = 0);

SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```

The output of this script is shown below. First, the setting up of all the tables:

```
DROP TABLE TABLE1; DROP TABLE TABLE2;
    TABLE1 DROPPED
    TABLE2 DROPPED
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (VALUE INTEGER);
    TABLE1 CREATED
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (VALUE INTEGER, I INTEGER);
    TABLE2 CREATED
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ((5), (3));
    INSERTED 2 ROWS
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ((5, 0), (5, 3), (3,0), 3, 0));
    INSERTED 4 ROWS
```

And display them to ensure they're as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1; SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
    VALUE
    -----
      5
      3
    VALUE   I
    -----   -
      5     0
      5     3
      3     0
      3     0
```

Then run the command to get rid of the relevant rows:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE VALUE IN                          
  (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY VALUE HAVING MAX(I) = 0);
    DELETED 1 ROW
```

And you can see that the 3` row has disappeared from table 1 as desired:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1; SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
    VALUE
    -----
      5
    VALUE   I
    -----   -
      5     0
      5     3
      3     0
      3     0
```

Comment: I complains at my semicolon. Says: Expecting ')', EXCEPT or UNION

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.value 
IN(
   SELECT table2.value 
   from table2
   GROUP BY table2.value
   HAVING MAX(table2.i) < 1
   )
AND TABLE1.Value2
IN(
   SELECT Table2.value2 
   from table2
   GROUP BY table2.value2
   HAVING MAX(table2.i) <1
   );

Comment: It's actually 2 values that has to match, but I didn't think it would matter so I just asked for how to do it with one.